# why the Sets' keys() value don't equal with Symbol.iterator, but kyes value equal with Symbol.iterator

Tags: javascript, set

```
const s = new Set();
s.add("hikari").add("hane");
console.log(s.keys() === s[Symbol.iterator]); //false
console.log(s.keys === s[Symbol.iterator]); //true
```

I declare a Set,and add two values in it. why the output of `s.keys() === s[Symbol.iterator]` is false, but `s.keys === s[Symbol.iterator]` is true? I founded it will jump into the same location of source code when I click the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

`s.keys` is a function object.
So is `s[Symbol.iterator]`.

They both will refer to the same code and are basically the same for Sets.

`s.keys()` actually executes this function and returns the iterator object.
So does `s[Symbol.iterator]()`.

But the following will always be different. One is a function another an iterator object.

```
console.log(typeof s.keys()) //"object"
console.log(typeof s[Symbol.iterator]); //"function"

//Hence this will always be false
console.log(s.keys() === s[Symbol.iterator]); //false
```

Even if you use function calls for both, the result will still be false, because two different objects are not equal in JS(because of different references)

```
console.log(s.keys() === s[Symbol.iterator]()); //false
console.log({} === {}) //false
```

Comment: now I know the reason `s.keys()` is not equal with `s[Symbol.iterator]`, but it's really fuse me why the output of `console.log(s.keys() === s[Symbol.iterator]())` is false, the reason is the reference return from two  function refer to different object ?  why they are not the same object?

Comment: Both the functions return the object with all properties same. But they return different objects. `let x = new Obj();` and `let y = new Obj();`, you can't expect them to be the same right even though every property is same. `===` checks for referential equality and only if the object instance is same will it return true. One blog to read https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: Nice. Consider upvoing/accepting this answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The `[Symbol.iterator]` property of any object, when it exists, returns the object's iterator. The `keys` property of a Set is also a function that returns the iterator - in a Set, the `keys` iterator (and the function that returns the iterator) is the exact same thing as the iterator over the whole object.

They're both functions.

```js
const s = new Set();
s.add("hikari").add("hane");
console.log(typeof s.keys);
```

And they both return objects - [iterable objects with a `next` method, a `value` property, and a `done` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

The objects aren't `===` to any other objects - they're generated anew each time `.keys()` or the `[Symbol.iterator]` property is called.